# Understanding Dilworth's theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, examples-counterexamples, order-theory

I am a graduate student and I am having a course on discrete mathematics.I am just introduced to Dilworth's theorem which states that:

*The minimum number of disjoint chains required to cover a finite poset is equal to the maximum size of antichain in that poset.*

I want to understand this theorem by means of examples.Can someone illustrate an example where I can clearly see the equality?I want to get a feel that this should be true.But,I am unable to do so.

Comment: It's easy to see for a single chain, and more generally easy to see for a disjoint union of chains. Past that things are tricky; for example I don't think it's at all obvious for the poset of subsets of a finite set.

Comment: One application is to prove the Erdös-Szekeres Theorem about the existence of monotonic sequences by defining a suitable partial order on sequences. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem#Dilworth's_theorem